# Contents clipped using autolayout in 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios, autolayout

i am using autolayout in my project. I added the contraints from the bottom to the top. Everything works fins in 4 inch screen . But screen is clipped when the project is run on 3.5 simulator.
[image: 4 inch]
[image: 3.5 inch]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshots, it looks like there is no space to fit all your elements.
One way to go about it is, dock the elements at the top of the screen using the `Top Space To Superview` constraint, and dock the elements at the bottom using the `Bottom Space To Superview` constraint.

When you do this, if there's not enough space available, you'll probably see some of your subviews overlapping around the middle.

You can consider solving this by using a `UIScrollView` as a top level subview and add all your subviews to the scrollView. The content height of the scrollView will be calculated based on your constraints. 
You can also manually set the contentView height after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find that sometimes I can't seem to get Autolayout to work exactly as I want. So its worth putting a check in your viewDidLoad to manually move objects around a bit if the screen size is a 3.5 inch screen like so:

In my example I will be using a Button:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (result.height == 480) {
        // 3.5 inch display
        button.frame = CGRectOffset(button.frame, 0, 89.0f);
    }

    if (result.height >= 568) {
        // 4 inch display
        // .....
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nassif Indeed, sometimes its just not great.